# UIButton image invisible

Tags: swift, uibutton

I'm very confused as to why this simple code is not working for setting the backgroundImage for my custom buttons. The buttons are clickable, but fully invisible. The button class is set correctly in the Interface Builder. The button type is set to Custom.

```
class DefaultButton: UIButton {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setupView()
}

override func layoutSubviews() {

}

func setupView() {
    setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "blue_button"), for: .normal)
}
```

Even if I set the backgroundImage in the interface builder, it doesn't work.

How do I set the backgroundImage for a UIButton??

Comment: `setImage(UIImage(named: "blue_button"), for: .normal)`

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `setImage` instead of `setBackgroundImage` as follows:

```
setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "blue_button"), for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me, the actual issue was that I was overriding the layoutSubviews() function. I wouldn't guess it would've made any effect if the function was empty...

Comment: when you override it you should always call `super.layoutSubviews()` in it

Comment: Wonderful, that's a great input! Now I have a much better understanding of what `super.xxxxxx()` means, thanks!